# Как в Python удалить дубли списка по вхождению подстроки?

Tags: python, list

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить следующую задачу.

Есть список строк, каждая строка условно делится на две части по разделителю точка с запятой.
В данном списке, мне нужно удалить дубли строк именно по первой части строки, до точки с запятой.

То есть, на входе имеем список вида:

```
[string1;drgedsgg,
string1;fdhvbvcbc,
string1;cfbddfd,
string2;cbgfghfh,
string2;cbdfdfddd,
string2;hjmggghhng,
string3;fgbfdbcccfdf,
string3;dfgdgfd,
string3;gdffgghgfhggh]
```

На выходе, нужно получить список вида:

```
[string1;drgedsgg,
string2;hjmggghhng,
string3;fgbfdbcccfdf]
```

Comment: через for идешь по списку, запоминаешь 1, если следующий равен 1 то удаляешь, и так пока не найдешь тот, что не равен, когда нашел запоминаешь его, дальше сравниваешь с ним и т.д

Comment: Почему для string1 оставляется первое значение, для string2 последнее, а для string3 опять первое?

Comment: в случае дупликатов какие строки оставлять - первые или последние?

Comment: Очередность никакой роли не играет. Вторая половина строки в алгоритме не учитывается. Главное, чтоб дублей по первой части строки не было, это единственное условие.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пройтись по всем строчкам, при этом записывая в отдельный лист уже использованные первые части этих строк.

```
sortedList = []
alreadyUsed = []
for item in list:
    isUsed = False
    for used in alreadyUsed:
        if used == item.split(';')[0]:
            isUsed = True
            break
    if not isUsed:
        sortedList.append(item)
        alreadyUsed.append(item.split(';')[0])

print(sortedList)
# ['string1;drgedsgg', 'string2;cbgfghfh', 'string3;fgbfdbcccfdf']
```

Если нужны последние строки из дублированных, просто в начале отрази начальный список list.

```
list.reverse()
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужные первые, то можно так -  собрать словарь `первые половинки:индекс в списке`. Сохранятся только последние, поэтому лист обходим в обратном порядке. И теперь соберем значения по этим индексам

```
d = {s.split(';')[0]:i for i,s in enumerate(lst[::-1])}
res = [lst[i] for i in d.values()]  
print(res)

# ['string1;cfbddfd', 'string2;hjmggghhng', 'string3;gdffgghgfhggh']
```